# SqlAlchemy get all strings (don't cast to boolean or datetime)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, etl

How can I change the way that sqlalchemy cast the return values of my select, so it only returns strings, instead of Booleans or Datetime objects? I'm reading from a postgresql db.

For example I'm getting this:

```
>>>result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table").first()
>>>result
(123, 'some string field', True, datetime.datetime(2015, 06, ....))
```

When I would like to get this:

```
>>>result
('123', 'some string field', 'true', '2015-06-13....')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
result = tuple([str(col_value) for col_value in result])
```

*If you would like to conversion to happen on the DB side, you will have to perform `cast(...)` function on each column separately.*

Comment: Yes, casting seems the way to go, as I don't want to have to go through all the values twice (I got millions of rows). Thanks!